# Drupal Commerce Multiple Saves

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm having a problem with drupal commerce and saving new products. When I click the save button twice (or as often as you can before the page reloads), the product gets saved multiple times. Is there any possibilty to stop multi-saves?
In a standard version, it should prevent that by checking the sku, but as I am using auto-sku module, every click generates a new sku.

Comment: What if you add some javascript to prevent multiple clicks?

Comment: This was one of my first ideas, but the only thing so far I've managed to do is, disable after the first click. Which is a problem when you did a mistake, and have to click a second time. Then the button is deactivated. I have to find out, when a click leads to an error / success and only allow success once.